# How android's SharedPreference is saved?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SharedPreferences file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566430/sharedpreferences-file)

Can you please tell me where does sharePreference of an android application save?
How can I download it to my pc and view it?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SharedPreferences file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566430/sharedpreferences-file) or [Android: Viewing SharedPreferences file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951418/android-viewing-sharedpreferences-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SharedPreferences are stored in an xml file in the app data folder, i.e.

> /data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/shared_prefs/YOUR_PREFS_NAME.xml

or the default preferences at:

> /data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/shared_prefs/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME_preferences.xml