# Cocos2d-x: Is there a way to get a content of CCUserDefault's file?

Tags: cocos2d-x

I need to get a content from a file in which CCUserDefault() stores its data. Is there a way to get it? I guess my storage is corrupted so I need to check its content.

I've tried following:

```
if ( cocos2d::CCUserDefault::sharedUserDefault()->isXMLFileExist() ) {
    cocos2d::CCLog( "XML exists!" );
} else {
    cocos2d::CCLog( "XML not exists!" );
}
```

So I get "XML not exists" on Android and iOS but a user setting successfully loads. Where CCUserDefault() stores its data now?

Answer (score 0):

Because cocos2d-x does not create xml file to store data in android and ios. A little digging into the `"CCUserDefault.cpp"` showed me this at the start of the file

```
  #if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM != CC_PLATFORM_IOS && CC_TARGET_PLATFORM != CC_PLATFORM_ANDROID)
```

which means that cocos2d-x does not use the conventional xml creating and storing data in these two platforms. 
I don't know about IOS, but in android, they may be using shared preferences now. As mentioned in this [link](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/boards/6/topics/17518) as well. To read share preference file, u have to write some code in JNI. Follow these posts for reference:

[Android: Viewing SharedPreferences file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951418/android-viewing-sharedpreferences-file)

[Where are shared preferences stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146106/where-are-shared-preferences-stored)

Answer (score 0):

In Mac the xml file of ccuserdefault is created in

```
/Users/yourusername/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/(select your     
version)7.0.3/Applications/(something like this)9C9FF1EB-0674-4FA9-A113    
D9E3DAD7B2CB/Library/Preferences/com.yourcompany.projectname.plist
```

here open this plist and you can see the key and the value which is stored on the key

Make sure to keep your library folder unhidden by running the command in terminal

```
chflags nohidden ~/Library
```