# Why is my data folder empty in DDMS perspective

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I was trying SharedPreferences and everything works fine. According to the tutorial, after I change some preferences, I should find a folder named shared_prefs and a XML file which contains my preferences under the data folder in DDMS perspective. But mine is empty, why? Btw, I am debugging with real Android phone. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `SharedPreferences` are private, you need to be root on your device to see what is in this folder.

Check this post for more details: [Android: Viewing SharedPreferences file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951418/android-viewing-sharedpreferences-file)

Comment: Thanks, the link helps. I think my data folder is empty because I am not using a virtual device to test the app.