# Where save file android app?

Tags: android

I am learning android and i have code:

```
public class SecondNetwork extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button go = (Button) findViewById(R.id.do_action);
        go.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    URL text = new URL("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?id=26648248@N04&amp;lang=en-us&amp;format=atom");
                     HttpURLConnection http= (HttpURLConnection) text.openConnection();

                     Log.i("Net", "length = " + http.getContentLength());
                     Log.i("Net", "respCode = " + http.getResponseCode());
                     Log.i("Net", "contentType = "+ http.getContentType());
                     Log.i("Net", "content = "+http.getContent());

                    InputStream isText = http.getInputStream();
                    byte[] bText = new byte[2048];
                    FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput ("file.out", MODE_PRIVATE);
                    int numAvailable = isText.available();

                    Log.i("Net", "available = " + numAvailable);

                    int readSize = 0;
                    while (readSize != -1) {
                        numAvailable = isText.available();
                        Log.i("Net", "available = " + numAvailable);

                        readSize = isText.read(bText);

                        if (readSize > 0) {
                            fos.write(bText, 0, readSize);
                        }
                        Log.i("Net", "readSize = " + readSize);

                    }

                    isText.close();
                    http.disconnect();
                    fos.close();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Net", "Error in network call", e);
                }

            }

        });
    }

}
```

The most important:

```
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput ("file.out", MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(bText, 0, readSize);
fos.close();
```

Where can I preview the contents of this file (file.out)?

If use system file explorer then i can't find this.

In DDMS eclipse doesn't have search engine.

I try (run as and debug as) in DDMS:

> data > data > your app id > files

but first folder data is empty.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What file system path is used by Android's Context.openFileOutput()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926027/what-file-system-path-is-used-by-androids-context-openfileoutput)

Comment: Thanks, but my folder data is empty.

Comment: please check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18862789/2367849

Comment: Thanks, please add new answer :)